# Shouldn't list1 always print out as its original value since i am equating list1 to list2.However in the output the execution stops and returns a err

Tags: python, list

```
list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

list2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

while True:

    list1.pop(0)

    list1=list2

    print(list1)
```

Comment: Eventually you'll run out of things to pop, what exactly is the error you're asking about?

Comment: `list1=list2` assigns both variables to the same list object

Comment: https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit if you want to visualize execution

Comment: but why is this happening tho,cause list2 is a different variable right?

Comment: @Codingbeginner `list1` points to the same list as `list2` so using either of those names will change the same list

Comment: i want to change the value of list1 to list2 tho how do i that then

Comment: it is in the answer of the duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hapen because you pass `list2` with address to `list1` then when you pop from `list1` you pop from `list2` too, see some iteration of your code. after three run of your `while True` your `list1` and `list2` is empty and when you pop from `list1` you got an error.

```
>>> list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> list2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> list1.pop(0)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list1=list2
>>> list1.pop(0)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list2
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If you change your code like below and use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) you don't get an error:

```
import copy
list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

while True:
    list1.pop(0)
    list1=copy.deepcopy(list2)
    print(list1)
```

Comment: but why is list2 getting affected isnt it a different variable

Comment: @Codingbeginner because `list1` and `list2` have same address they are one variable with different name and when you pop from `list1` you pop from `list2`

Comment: @Codingbeginner read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63533055/1740577)